# Makefile with variable number of targets

Tags: makefile, pipeline

I am attempting to do a data pipeline with a `Makefile`. I have a big file that I want to split in smaller pieces to process in parallel. The number of subsets and the size of each subset is not known beforehand. For example, this is my file

```
$ for i in {1..100}; do echo $i >> a.txt; done
```

The first step in Makefile should compute the ranges,... lets make them fixed for now

```
ranges.txt: a.txt
   or i in 0 25 50 75; do echo  $$(($$i+1))'\t'$$(($$i+25)) >> $@; done
```

Next step should read from ranges.txt, and create a target file for each range in ranges.txt, a_1.txt, a_2.txt, a_3.txt, a_4.txt. Where a_1.txt contains lines 1 through 25, a_2.txt lines 26-50, and so on... Can this be done?

Comment: You can't generate files and use them as input to targets in a single make run directly. You can do this sort of thing by teaching make how to generate an included makefile though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what version of make you're using, but I'll assume GNU make.  There are a few ways of doing things like this; I wrote a set of blog posts about [metaprogramming in GNU make](http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/) (by which I mean having make generate its own rules automatically).

If it were me I'd probably use the [constructed include files](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-include-files/) method for this.  So, I would have your rule above for `ranges.txt` instead create a makefile, perhaps `ranges.mk`.  The makefile would contain a set of targets such as `a_1.txt`, `a_2.txt`, etc. and would define target-specific variables defining the start and stop values.  Then you can `-include` the generated `ranges.mk` and make will rebuild it.  One thing you haven't described is when you want to recompute the ranges: does this really depend on the contents of `a.txt`?

Anyway, something like:

```
.PHONY: all
all:

ranges.mk: a.txt   # really? why?
        for i in 0 25 50 75; do \
            echo 'a_$$i.txt : RANGE_START := $$(($$i+1))'; \
            echo 'a_$$i.txt : RANGE_END   := $$(($$i+25))'; \
            echo 'TARGETS += a_$$i.txt'; \
        done > $@

-include ranges.mk

all: $(TARGETS)
$(TARGETS) : a.txt   # seems more likely
        process --out $@ --in $< --start $(RANGE_START) --end $(RANGE_END)
```

(or whatever command; you don't give any example).

Comment: So, when you change `a.txt` it regenerates the ranges AND the output files?  Ok.  Anyway this works as written for that situation.

Comment: ranges will be generated by a binning algorithm that processes information in a.txt, let me test this approach, thanks for the info!